# Polymer Firebase. Arrays in Objects

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer-1.0, polymerfire

Im using polymer and firebase and I was wondering how to create an array of objects inside an object.

[image: Like the object above]

I want nested data like in the object the groups single object whereby we have members and the names inside it

```
      this.$.query.ref.push({
        name: this.$.crewName.value,
        description: this.$.crewDescription.value,
        createddate: new Date().toString(),
        creator: this.$.createcrewlogin.user.uid,
        slug: sluggedname
      });
```

With a simple push method like this .How do I achieve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write to the Firebase Database from JavaScript, you pass in a [standard JSON object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). This means that you can just nest the objects inside the object you pass to `push()`:

```
  this.$.query.ref.push({
    name: this.$.crewName.value,
    description: this.$.crewDescription.value,
    createddate: new Date().toString(),
    creator: this.$.createcrewlogin.user.uid,
    slug: sluggedname,
    subobject: {
      techpioneers: true,
      womentechmakers: true
    }
  });
```

Comment: And What If I was to update the `suboject` object.. How would I do that

Comment: That depends on what subobject you want to update. You'd first have to query to find that object's key and then `ref.child(key).child(subobject).update({ newkey: true, womentechmakers: false, techpioneers: null })`. This will add a new key, change `womentechmakers` to false and remove `techpioneers`.

Comment: Great.. I've understood